# how to get this string using python

Tags: python, string

i have a list like this :

```
a=[1000,200,30]
```

and i want to get a list like this :

```
['01000','00200','00030']
```

so what can i do ,

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> a=[1000,200,30]
>>> [str(e).zfill(5) for e in a]
['01000', '00200', '00030']
```

[str.zfill](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill)

Comment: I thought that might choke on -30 but no so, it correctly gives you `-0030`. +1.

Answer (score 5):

`str.format()` is the preferred way to do this if you are using Python >=2.6

```
>>> a=[1000, 200, 30]
>>> map("{0:05}".format, a)
['01000', '00200', '00030']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
a = [1000,200,30]
b = ["%05d" % (i) for i in a]
print b
```

The number tells the width and the leading zero says that you want leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [formatting strings in Python](http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
map(lambda x:str(x).zfill(5),a)
```

Comment: I _hate_ this answer since all that lambda stuff makes a mockery of my beautiful grade-school teaching language, but it _is_ useful, so +1 :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, it's also possible to pass a `str.format` as the first arg to map. See my answer